# mouse listener not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, mouselistener

My code:

```
package a2048;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    public GameWindow() {

        add(new Main());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(409, 435);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("2048");
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameWindow();
    }
}
```

that is one class, the other:

```
    package a2048;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    int randx, randy, quit;
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3 ,b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3, d4;

    int GetRandom(int min, int max)
    {
       int range = (max - min) + 1;  
       double rand = (Math.random() * range) + min;
       return (int) rand;

    }

    public Main() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        quit = 0;

        a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = b1 = b2 = b3 = b4 = c1 = c2 = c3 = c4 = d1 = d2 = d3 = d4 = 0;

        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 0);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 100, 500, 100);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 200, 500, 200);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 300, 500, 300);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 400, 500, 400);      

        g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(300, 0, 300, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(400, 0, 400, 500);

        Font myFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 75);
        g2d.setFont(myFont);

        while(quit == 0)
        {
            randx = GetRandom(1, 4);
            randy = GetRandom(1, 4);

            if(randx == 1)
            {
                if(randy == 1 && a1 == 0)
                {
                    a1 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 2 && a2 == 0)
                {
                    a2 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 3 && a3 == 0)
                {
                    a3 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 4 && a4 == 0)
                {
                    a4 = 2;
                }
            }

            else if(randx == 2)
            {
                if(randy == 1 && b1 == 0)
                {
                    b1 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 2 && b2 == 0)
                {
                    b2 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 3 && b3 == 0)
                {
                    b3 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 4 && b4 == 0)
                {
                    b4 = 2;
                }
            }

            else if(randx == 3)
            {
                if(randy == 1 && c1 == 0)
                {
                    c1 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 2 && c2 == 0)
                {
                    c2 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 3 && c3 == 0)
                {
                    c3 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 4 && c4 == 0)
                {
                    c4 = 2;
                }
            }

            else if(randx == 4)
            {
                if(randy == 1 && d1 == 0 && a1 == 0)
                {
                    d1 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 2 && d2 == 0 && a1 == 0)
                {
                    d2 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 3 && d3 == 0 && a1 == 0)
                {
                    d3 = 2;
                }
                else if(randy == 4 && d4 == 0 && a1 == 0)
                {
                    d4 = 2;
                }
            }

            if(a1 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a1), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(a2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a2), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(a3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a3), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(a4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a4), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(b1> 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b1), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(b2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b2), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(b3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b3), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(b4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b4), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(c1 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c1), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(c2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c2), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(c3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c3), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(c4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c4), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(d1 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d1), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(d2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d2), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(d3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d3), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);
            if(d4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d4), (randx * 100) - 70, (randy * 100) - 25);

            quit = 1;
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();   
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        repaint(); 
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        repaint(); 
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        repaint(); 
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        repaint(); 
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        a1 = 5;
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the mouseClicked method is not doing anything when I click the window. What i want it to do is set a1 to 5 and then print that on the screen, but instead it is simply not doing anything. What do I change to make it so that MouseListener is working correctly?

Comment: What do you want your `MouseListener` to listen to?  You need to `addMouseListener()` to register it to actually listen to something.

Comment: I would like MouseListener to be able to detect when I click. also, where should I add addMouseListener() to my program... could you give me an example?

Comment: When you click anywhere on the window?

Comment: yep. Later I will want it to detect where you click, but for now, I would like it to be anywhere.

Comment: Have ya read the MouseListener tutorial? It's all well explained there, and Google will help you find it.

Answer (score 3):

A `MouseListener` needs to be registered with what it is listening *to* to be able to do anything.

Whenever you click the mouse on something, it will generate a `MouseEvent` and invoke methods on anything which is listening to it, passing that event in as a parameter.

You seem to be implementing your listener as part of your `JPanel`, so in addition to adding it as a component in your `GameWindow`, you also need to register it as a mouse listener on the window.

Replace

```
add(new Main());
```

with

```
Main main = new Main();
addMouseListener(main);
add(main);
```

---

EDIT

A cleaner way to do this suggested by HovercraftFullOfEels would be to have the 
**Main** `JPanel` listen for mouse events on itself.  To do this you would call `addMouseListener()` in the constructor of Main rather than in the enclosing `JFrame`:

```
public Main() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it usually be better to add the MouseListener to the Main JPanel and not the JFrame?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not sure what is considered the best practice in gui design these days.  I've tried it both ways in the OPs program and it doesn't seem to make any functional difference.

Comment: @azurefrog: no, it won't make a difference here, but it will as soon as he cares about where the button is being pressed. Say for instance if he wants to draw a dot in the main JPanel at the button press location. If you add the MouseListener to the JFrame, you will mess things up. I would venture to guess that 99.9% of the time, in this situation the MouseListener should not be added to the top-level window.

Comment: Well, that's a good point, I'll update my answer accordingly.